# Alternatives For vh and vw

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to design a responsive web page so I am trying to avoid using pixel values. But sometimes, for example when trying to limit the width of a text containing div, I cannot use percentages since the width of the contianer is not known and going to be determined by the content inside. And due to the way CSS works, I cannot give a width value with reference to the container div higher in the html hierarchy.

So I thought of using vw, but since I am using min-width, max-width values on the body, it will not work properly outside those values. What can I use instead to refer to the body width?

**Edit:**

Since an example was asked for, I provided below an example whereby percentage did not work. Trying to make the span width 10% of the outermost container with no luck. Here is the jsfiddle link also: https://jsfiddle.net/68ha60p6/

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:60px;">
<div style="float:right; height:100%;padding-right:1%"> 
<button style="display:inline-block; height:70%;background-color:green; color:white;border:none; padding:0;">
<span style="display:inline-block; max-width:10%; text-overflow:ellipses;overflow:hidden; max-height:100%;text-align:center;white-space:no-wrap;">John John</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a pretty tough question to answer without you showing any style or markup. It sounds like `%` is what you need, but you've said they're a no-go.

Comment: Please show us your code :)

Comment: I understand the problem from your description, but it's tough to help without a visual. Can you put some code on JSFiddle to show us what you're working with and the desired behavior you want? There might be an outside-the-box solution.

Comment: @DBS Added a sample code.

Comment: @MartinP. Added a sample code.

Comment: @JonUleis Added a sample code.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot give a width value with reference to the container div higher
>   in the html hierarchy.

You absolutely can.

Have a look at the example below.

You'll see that the width of the parent container is not explicitly stated (it's determined by the content of the first subcontainer). Regardless, the second subcontainer's width is `50%` of its parent's.

```css
div {
margin: 6px;
padding: 6px;
}

.container {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid rgb(255,0,0);
}

.subcontainer1 {
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,255);
}

.subcontainer2 {
width: 50%;
margin: 6px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0,255,0);
}

div p {
line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="subcontainer1">
<p>I am a long sentence and I will define the width both of this sub-container and of the overall parent container.
</div>

<div class="subcontainer2">
<p>I am half the width of the overall parent container.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I editted the question adding a sample snippet whereby it does not work. Could you comment on that?

Comment: If you give an element a percentage-based width, this value is relative to its parent. So in your snippet, you are stating that the `span` should be 10% the width of the `button`.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I am talking about. How can I get the desired effect without giving max-width hard coded pixel values without using vw?

Comment: The width of the span can be a percentage of the width of the button, which can be a percentage of the width of the div containing it, which can be a percentage of the width of the parent div, which can be a percentage of the viewport. But, at present, only the parent div has a width.

Comment: Vw will also not help you i think. In most cases you will give your site wrapper a maximum width, while the viewport can be much bigger (2000 px and greater).